# Bash Shell: grepping between specific string and delimiter?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to check if "slave=new" string exists below the string "localhost" in a specific pattern. The example of the pattern is shown below. The idea is to start checking from "localhost" string and end up before ";;" delimiter ?
I figured way to check if "slave=new" is on second row after localhost,

```
grep -A1 "localhost" file| tail -1
```

but there is possibility to be placed on the rest of the rows before ";;".

Here's the pattern:

```
(frasdsp221)
   slave=new
   blablabla
   tintirimintiri
;;

  (localhost)
   blobloblo
   slave=new
   blablabla
;;


  (asdasd421)
   slave=new
   blablabla
   tintirimintiri
;;
```

Comment: what output do you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do this, with something like:

```
awk '
    /(localhost)/               { looking = 1 }
    (looking==1) && /slave=new/ { print "found it"; exit }
    /;;/                        { looking = 0 }
' inputfile
```

It simply uses a `looking` flag which is turned on when you see a `(localhost)` line and turned off when you see a `;;` line.

If you see a `slave=new` line at any point while the flag is on, it tells you about it and exits so as not to waste further resources.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu-awk you can use a custom `RS` (record separator):

```
awk -v RS=';;' '/\(localhost\).*slave=new/' file
```

Since we're using `RS=';;'` awk gives us each block in single record and then we can search using simple regex `/\(localhost\).*slave=new/` to make sure both `(localhost)` and `slave=new` exist in same block.

**Output:**

```
  (localhost)
   blobloblo
   slave=new
   blablabla
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using grep:

```
$ grep -zPo '\(localhost\)(.|\n)*?slave=new(.|\n)*?;;' file
(localhost)
   blobloblo
   slave=new
   blablabla
;;
```